# AMP (accelerated mobile page) in HubSpot

Tags: amp-html, hubspot, hubspot-cms

Is it possible to code AMP webpages and landing pages in HubSpot from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. Right now HubSpot has an automatic AMP support for blogs. There is a basic configurator for customizing the AMP blog look and feel but does not give you full control.